# Event on click legend (doughnut chart) - Chart.js -

Tags: javascript, chart.js2

I'm trying to add custom event to legend in doughnut chart using chart.js but I don't know how.

I'm using this [example](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2437)

```
var original = Chart.defaults.global.legend.onClick;
Chart.defaults.global.legend.onClick = function(e, legendItem) {
  /* do custom stuff here */
  original.call(this, e, legendItem);
};
```

I'm getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_meta' of undefined

Any suggestion??

Comment: can you please include the entire code? or better have a jsfiddle

Comment: @alejandro where you able to achieve this ?